# Running Pytest on Multiple Devices in Parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, automated-tests, adb, pytest

I have 3 devices connected to my computer and I want to run pytest in parallel on each of them.

I there any way to do it, either with pytest or with adb?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Selenium Grid for runs on multiple devices.